# Converting Geojson to Shapefile in Javascript using shp-write

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, require

I'm using Mapbox, and I'm trying to convert a Geojson to a zipped shapefile using [shp-write](https://github.com/mapbox/shp-write). But when I follow the [example](https://github.com/mapbox/shp-write#example) given on the GitHub page, I'm getting a "ReferenceError: require is not defined" error on this line:

```
var shpwrite = require('shp-write');
```

This is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajkishan16/3xff9zmy/) in which you can test this. I'm relatively new to JavaScript, and haven't had to use the 'require()' function before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jsfiddle you provided includes several external resources, among which a [`shpwrite`](https://unpkg.com/shp-write@latest/shpwrite.js) delivered by [unpkg](https://unpkg.com/#/) that you may be missing.

Usually `require` [doesn't exist in your browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19059825/2457168). You would need to execute it with Node.js or use a module bundler like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), but Unpkg takes care of it for you.

So adding:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/shp-write@latest/shpwrite.js"></script>
```

on your page should make it work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. So you mean that in the case of this jsfiddle, since I've already added that unpkg link for shp-write under External Resources, I can just remove the entire "var shpwrite = require('shp-write');" line and it should work? I did that in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajkishan16/3xff9zmy/1/) and got an error "Error: This method has been removed in JSZip 3.0, please check the upgrade guide". Is that a separate issue?

Comment: There is an issue about this error on the shpwrite Github page. You should try the solution in the last comment until they fix it https://github.com/mapbox/shp-write/issues/48

Comment: I noticed that issue as well and used the workaround given in the solution, and now it works! So thanks a lot for your help.