# leaflet shp-write to convert geojson to shapefile

Tags: leaflet, geojson, shapefile

I'm trying to convert a Geojson to a zipped shapefile using shp-write.
But when I follow the example given on the GitHub page https://github.com/mapbox/shp-write#example
I'm getting a "ReferenceError: require is not defined" error on this line:

```
var shpwrite = require('shp-write');
```

This question was posted at [Converting Geojson to Shapefile in Javascript using shp-write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48325664/converting-geojson-to-shapefile-in-javascript-using-shp-write), but I was unable to access the updated file at https://jsfiddle.net/rajkishan16/3xff9zmy/

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Please check the referenced question - there is no updated file, you need to follow the answer.